# leftist heap implementation in c++

Tags: c++, leftist-tree

good afternoon, i am trying to implement leftist heap
here is my header file and source file
for header file

```
#include<iostream>
template<class comparable>
class leftistheap;

template<class comparable>
class leftistnode
{
    comparable element;
    leftistnode *left;
    leftistnode *right;
    int  npl;
    leftistnode(const comparable  &theelement,leftistnode *lt=NULL,leftistnode *rt=NULL,int np=0):element(thelement),left(lt),right(rt),npl(np){}
    friend class leftistheap<comparable>;
    };
template<class comparable>
class leftistheap
{
public:
    leftistheap();
    leftistheap (const leftistheap &rhs);
    ~leftistheap();
    bool isempthy()const ;
    bool isfull() const;
    const comparable &findmin() const;
    void insert(const comparable &x);
    void deletemin();
    void deletemin(comparable &minitem);
    void makeempthy();
    void merge(leftistheap &rhs);

    const leftistheap & operator=(const leftistheap &rhs);
private:
    leftistnode<comparable>*root;
    leftistnode<comparable>*merge(leftistnode<comparable>*h1,leftistnode<comparable>*h2)const;
     leftistnode<comparable> * merge1( leftistnode<comparable> *h1,
                                              leftistnode<comparable> *h2 ) const;
            void swapchildren( leftistnode<comparable> * t ) const;
            void reclaimmemory( leftistnode<comparable> * t ) const;
            leftistnode<comparable> * clone( leftistnode<comparable> *t ) const;
        };
```

and source file

```
#include<iostream>
#include "leftist.h"
using namespace std;
template<class comparable>
leftistheap<comparable>::leftistheap()
{
    root=NULL;
}
template<class comparable>
leftistheap<comparable>::leftistheap(const leftistheap<comparable>&rhs)
{
    root=NULL;
    *this=rhs;
}
template<class comparable>
leftistheap<comparable>::~leftistheap()
{
    makeempthy();
}
template<class comparable>
void leftistheap<comparable>::merge(leftistheap &rhs)
{
    if(this==&rhs)
         return;
    root=merge(root,rhs.root);
    rhs.root=NULL;

}
template<class comparable>
leftistnode<comparable>*leftistheap<comparable>::merge(leftistnode <comparable>*h1,leftistnode<comparable>*h2)const
{

    if(h1==NULL)
         return h2;
    if(h2==NULL)
         return h1;
    if(h1->element<h2->element)
        return merge1(h1,h2);
    else
        return merge1(h2,h1);


}

template<class comparable>
leftistnode<comparable>*leftistheap<comparable>::merge1(leftistnode<comparable>*h1,leftistnode<comparable>*h2)const
{

    if(h1->left==NULL)
        h1->left=h2;
    else
    {

        h1->right=merge(h1->right,h2);
        if(h1->left->npl<h1->right->npl)
            swapchildren(h1);
        h1->npl=h1->right->npl+1;






    }
     return h1;

}
template<class comparable>
void leftistheap<comparable>::swapchildren(leftistnode<comparable>*t)const
{
    leftistnode<comparable> *temp=t->left;
    t->left=t->right;
    t->right=emp;


}
template<class comparable>
void leftistheap<comparable>::insert(const comparable &x)
{
    root=merge(new leftistnode<comparable>(x),root);

}
template<class comparable>
const comparable &leftistheap<comparable>::findmin()const
    {
         if(isempty())
             throw Underflow();
    return root->element;


}
template<class comparable>
void leftistheap<comparable>::deletemin()
{
    if(isempty())
         throw Underflow();
    leftistnode<comparable>*oldroot=root;
    root=merge(root->left,root->right);
    delete oldroot;


}
template<class comparable>
void leftistheap<comparable>::deletemin(comparable & minitem)
{
    minitem=findmin();
    deletemin();

}
template<class comparable>
bool leftistheap<comparable>::isempthy() const
{


return root=NULL;
}
template<class comparable>
bool leftistheap<comparable>::isfull( ) const
        {
            return false;
        }

template <class comparable>
void leftistheap<comparable>::makeempthy()
        {
            reclaimmemory( root );
            root = NULL;
        }
        template<class comparable>
        const leftistheap<comparable>& leftistheap<comparable >::operator=(const leftistheap<comparable>& rhs)
        {
            if(this != &rhs)
            {
            makeempthy();
            root=clone(rhs.root);

            }
            return *this;
        }
        template<class comparable>
        void leftistheap<comparable>::reclaimmemory(leftistnode<comparable>*t) const
        {
            if(t!=NULL)
            {
                reclaimmemory(t->left);
                reclaimmemory(t->right);
                 delete t;


            }


        }
        template<class comparable>
        leftistnode<comparable>*leftistheap<comparable>::clone(leftistnode<comparable> *t)const
        {

            if(t==NULL)
                 return NULL;
            else
                return new leftistnode<comparable>( t->element, clone( t->left ),
                                              clone( t->right ), t->npl );
        }


int main()
{
    int numitems=100;
    leftistheap<int>h;
    leftistheap<int>h1;
    leftistheap<int>h2;
    int i=37;
    for(i=37;i!=0;i=(i+37)%numitems)
        if(i%2==0)
            h1.insert(i);
        else
            h.insert(i);
    h.merge(h1);
    h2=h;
     for( i = 1; i < numitems; i++ )
            {
                int x;
                h2.deletemin( x );
                if( x != i )
                    cout << "Oops! " << i << endl;
            }

            if (! h1.isempthy( ) )
                cout << "Oops! h1 should have been empty!" << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

but i am getting these errors, please help me why are these error?i have declared functions as const,but i am not modifing it,so what is problem?i am trying just to  define this functions and  this is all what i wont to do,the same problem is also  with root,why compiler says,that i am trying to change value of root?isempthy() function just checks if (root==NULL),but it does not change it's value,so i am really confused,will my code compile in case of i remove const  keywords?will not it change main behavior of code?i am new  here and sorry for  posting so large code,but to make code more clearly,i though post header and source file together for simplifying task for you,please help me guys,i am happy that there exist so good site.i would be happy in case of getting help from you
errors are :

```
2010\projects\leftist_heap\leftist_heap\leftist_heap.cpp(115): error C3490: 'root' cannot be modified because it is being accessed through a const object
1>          2010\projects\leftist_heap\leftist_heap\leftist_heap.cpp(112) : while compiling class template member function 'bool leftistheap<comparable>::isempthy(void) const'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              comparable=int
1>          ]
1>          2010\projects\leftist_heap\leftist_heap\leftist_heap.cpp(169) : see reference to class template instantiation 'leftistheap<comparable>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              comparable=int
1>          ]
1>2010\projects\leftist_heap\leftist_heap\leftist_heap.cpp(115): warning C4800: 'leftistnode<comparable> *const ' : forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false' (performance warning)
1>          with
1>          [
1>              comparable=int
1>          ]
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change implementation of your `isempty` member function to (logic is to check whether tree is empty or not) :

```
template<class comparable>
bool leftistheap<comparable>::isempthy() const
{
return root==NULL;
}
```

Comment: but i have does so,what is wrong

Comment: @AleksiBeriashvili you're assigning root = null , not comparing i.e root == null

Comment: yes yes i have checked,thanks a lot of,one question how to print value of leftistheaps?

Comment: @AleksiBeriashvili that sounds like a completely different question. So you should make another question for that (And please don't include the whole code again...).

Answer (score 3):

```
template<class comparable>
bool leftistheap<comparable>::isempthy() const
{


return root=NULL;
}
```

this is your problem - const after the method means that it will not modify the state of the object, but it does by changing root's value.